# Fill the diagonal and diagonal+1 in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want a matrix with 0 everywhere and the diagonal and diagonal +1 has 0.5 values.

I create the matrix with the following code:

```
n = 10
transProbs = matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
```

Then, filling the diagonal with:

```
diag(transProbs) = 0.5
```

The matrix now looks the following:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0   0.0
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.0
[10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.5
```

However, I want it to be:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5   0.0
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
[10,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.5
```

**Edit:**

This matrix will be used in `library(HMM)`, `initHMM` as the `transProbs` matrix.

My desired output for `emissionProbs` is:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2   0.2
 [2,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.2
 [3,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.2
 [9,]  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.2
[10,]  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2   0.2
```

Note that it is the diag +/-2 that is filled with 0.2. In the first matrix it is the diag +1 that is filled with 0.5. This means that in the end, the probabilities might "overlap" and get in the bottom left corner.

Comment: I believe the second argument of diag is k, you can use this for the off-diagonal

Comment: @MichaelChirico Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 4):

`diag(transProbs[,-1]) = 0.5` will do it

In my terminal, the output is:

```
transProbs
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5   0.0
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
[10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.5
```

Afterwards, you can add the last "out of nowhere" 0.5 with: 
`transProbs[10, 1] = 0.5`

Comment: The problem is now that we are missing 0.5 in row 10 column 1. Maybe it will be better with a for loop after all... :(

Comment: Since that one does not seem to follow any rule (it's just there "out of nowhere"), I recommend adding it manually, with ```transProbs[10, 1] = 0.5```. Actually, I believe you would need to add it manually even with a for loop. I have edited for convenience

Comment: Thanks, I have now however updated the question since I would a more general form for creating these matrices.

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg An update of a question should clarify some details of the original question, but not modify it and significantly broaden its scope. If people try to help you with a specific question, it could be frustrating for them to learn later that you are actually looking for something different.

Comment: @RHertel I totally get that, I should have been more clear that I wanted it on a general form.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the fact that matrices are vectors with a `dim` attribute.

```r
n <- 10
m <- 10
transProbs = matrix(0.0, nrow = n, ncol = m)

diag(transProbs) <- 0.5
transProbs[(1:(m - 1)) * (n + 1)] <- 0.5
transProbs
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [2,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0   0.0
#>  [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5   0.0
#>  [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
#> [10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The sequence `(1:(m - 1)) * (n + 1)` selects all matrix elements one off from the diagonal.

**Edit**

You can achieve want you ask in the edit taking the rest of the modulus of the same sequence (plus a shift) wrt the total number of elements in the sum, i.e.

```r
n <- 10
m <- 10
transProbs = matrix(0.0, nrow = n, ncol = m)

diag(transProbs) <- 0.2
transProbs[((1:m) * (n + 1)) %% (n * m)] <- 0.2
transProbs[((1:m) * (n + 1) + m) %% (n * m)] <- 0.2
transProbs[((1:m) * (n + 1) + 7 * m) %% (n * m)] <- 0.2
transProbs[((1:m) * (n + 1) + 8 * m) %% (n * m)] <- 0.2

transProbs
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2   0.2
#>  [2,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.2
#>  [3,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [4,]  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0   0.0
#>  [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.0
#>  [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.2
#>  [9,]  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.2
#> [10,]  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2   0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can determine the value of the shift (i.e. `+m`, `+7m` and `+8m`) looking at column where the sequence starts and subtracting 2. For example, to generate the sequence which starts in the third column you have to sum `(3 - 2)*m` which is simply `m`.

I hope its clear.

Comment: Thanks, I have now however updated the question since I would a more general form for creating these matrices.

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg, I modified the answer according to your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this solution, but it does the job:

```r
element_on_diagonal <- 0.5
element_above_and_below_diaginal <- 0.2

a <- diag(x = element_on_diagonal,
          nrow = 10)

for(i in seq_len(length.out = ncol(x = a)))
{
  temp <- sapply(X = setdiff(x = seq(from = (i - 2),
                                     to = (i + 2)),
                             y = i),
                 FUN = function(j) if (j %in% 1:10) j else if (j != 0) j %% 10 else 10)
  a[temp, i] <- element_above_and_below_diaginal
}

a
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2   0.2
#>  [2,]  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.2
#>  [3,]  0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [4,]  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0   0.0
#>  [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.0   0.0
#>  [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2  0.2   0.0
#>  [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.5  0.2   0.2
#>  [9,]  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.5   0.2
#> [10,]  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2   0.5
```

Comment: Note that you are now mixing 0.5 and 0.2, they should be different matrices.
However, with some modification this will work.

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg I started with your original problem, which had `0.5`, and then you changed your question. Anyway, the only "modification" you need is in the very first line with `element_on_diagonal` to get the 2nd matrix in your question as of now. To get the 1st matrix, all you have to do is substitute `setdiff(...)` to `i - 1`, and the `sapply` is a bit too much for that case. It's better to make a function.

Answer (score 0):

First create a function to shift a vector to the left and right (note - there is almost certainly a library or function that already does this but I couldn't find it!)

```
shiftSeq <- function(n, shift){
    #return vector 1:n, but start shifted
    # e.g. shiftSeq(5,shift=1) returns c(2,3,4,5,1)
    # e.g. shiftSeq(5,shift=-1) returns c(5,1,2,3,4)

    if(shift>=1){
        res <- c((shift+1):n, 1:(shift))
    } else if(shift==0){
        res <- 1:n
    } else{
        res <- c((n+1+shift):n, 1:(n+shift))
    }

    return(res)
}

> shiftSeq(5,shift=1)
[1] 2 3 4 5 1
```

We'll use this `shiftSeq` function inside another function (below).  The idea is to use `apply` with `shiftSeq` to shift each of the columns in the 'building block' diagonal matrix up and down, which we do several times, each time accumulating this shifted matrix in the result matrix.

The key is to set `rowShift` and `colShift` arguments correctly...

```
createTranProb <- function(n, prob, rowShift, colShift){
    # create transition probability matrix of size nxn
    #  - prob is non-zero prob
    #  - rowShift is number of rows to move prob down
    #  - colShift is number of cols to move prob to right

    shifts = setdiff(c(-rowShift:colShift), 0)
    matDiag <- diag(n)*prob
    matRes <- matDiag

    for(i in shifts){
        matRes <- matRes +
            apply(matDiag, 2, 
                  function(x) x[shiftSeq(n,i)])
    }
    return(matRes)
}
```

It works for the prob=0.5 case:

```
> createTranProb(10, 0.5, rowShift=0, colShift=1)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5   0.0
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
[10,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.5
```

As it does for prob=0.2 if we set `rowShift=2` and `colShift=2`:

```
> createTranProb(10, 0.2, 2, 2)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2   0.2
 [2,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.2
 [3,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.2
 [9,]  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.2   0.2
[10,]  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2   0.2
```

Just for fun, I've added one with prob=0.33333:

```
> createTranProb(10, 0.33333, 1, 1)
         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]   [,10]
 [1,] 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333
 [2,] 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
 [3,] 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
 [4,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
 [5,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
 [6,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
 [7,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000
 [8,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.00000
 [9,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333
[10,] 0.33333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.33333 0.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use matrix indexing (allows you to replace rows according to "coordinates"); if you look at the source code for `diag<-` (`` print(`diag<-`) ``), you'll see it does this for the simpler diagonal-only case.

```
NN = nrow(transProbs)
idx = seq_len(NN)
transProbs[cbind(idx, idx)] = .5 # replace diagonal
transProbs[cbind(idx[-NN], idx[-NN] + 1L)] = .5 # replace off-diagonal

transProbs
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#  [2,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#  [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#  [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#  [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
#  [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
#  [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0   0.0
#  [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5   0.0
#  [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
# [10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.5
```

You could also do this in one `[<-` call but it's a bit uglier/harder to read:

```
transProbs[cbind(c(idx, idx[-NN]), c(idx, idx[-NN] + 1L))] = .5
```

This might be *slightly* more efficient but because only the first `[<-` call copies `transProbs` (see `?tracemem` and `.Internal(inspect(transProbs))`), I thinkt he difference should be small.